# Get observableArray of unique values from another obseravableArray

Tags: arrays, knockout.js, unique, ko.observablearray

I'm having data like:

```
    { mealName: "sandwich", price: 0 },
    { mealName: "lobster", price: 34.95 },
    { mealName: "whole zebra", price: 290 },
    { mealName: "whole zebra", price: 290 },
    { mealName: "sandwich", price: 290 },
    { mealName: "whole zebra", price: 290 }
```

And I want to get observableArray like:

```
{ mealName: "sandwich"},
{ mealName: "whole zebra"},
{ mealName: "lobster"}
```

I've tried to reproduce it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmnkygyd/3/), but something is wrong

Comment: better try this which is cleaner and easy to understand . http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/rtr361vf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unique doesn't have to be an observable array as the availableMeals is not an observable array, but since you asked I used a computed.

First I sort the array using a custom sort function. I used concat to create a copy as I didn't want to modify the order of the original array. I then loop through the sorted array and remove any duplicates:

```
self.unique = ko.computed(function() {
     var sortedItems = self.availableMeals.concat().sort(function(left, right) { return left.mealName == right.mealName ? 0 : (left.mealName < right.mealName ? -1 : 1) });

     var meal;

     for (var i = 0; i < sortedItems.length; i++) {                 
         if (!meal || meal != sortedItems[i].mealName) {
             meal = sortedItems[i].mealName;
         }
         else {
             sortedItems.splice(i, 1);
             i--;
         }
     }

     return sortedItems;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz38kobh/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueMeals = ko.computed(function () {
    var uniqueMealNames = mealData().reduce(function(uniqueMeals, meal) {
        if(uniqueMeals.indexOf(meal.mealName) === -1) {
            uniqueMeals.push(meal.mealName);
        }
        return uniqueMeals;
    }, []);

    return uniqueMealNames.map(function(mealName) {
        return {mealName: mealName};
    });
});
```

Some suggestions: it's probably be better to store the unique values in an array of strings, not objects, i.e. `["sandwich", "whole zebra", "lobster"]`.  If so, you can drop the last line from my above code.

Also, you might consider looking into the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) library.  With lodash, this would be:

```
var uniqueMeals = ko.computed(function () {
    return _.unique(_.pluck(mealData, "mealName"));
})
```